# jasper ireport create table with number of rows

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is it possible to create a table with number of rows? I want the rows to contain 
static text + parameter for each row?

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: I don't know how to add the rows..this is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest and easiest thing to do may be to create a subreport with the data you want, and then add that subreport to your report.